# AutoIT C# integration

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am trying to automate a software by using the autoit library integrating it with my C# application, If someone has a solution then please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to adding the autoit class library to your project. Go to Solution Explorer - right click Refences - select Add Reference.[image]

Click Browse tab and go to C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\AutoItX\AutoItX3.dll
[image]

Autoit class library ready to used.[image]

Comment: it is better to add it as a nuget package.  this keeps it up to date and will let it work in a repo.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can reference to AutoItX3.dll
2. You can use the automation library which created by me. Hope it could help you.
   [UIAutomation Libary download](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Jacob.UIAutomation/)

Comment: any complete tutorials on behalf of autoit under c# ?

Comment: sorry do not have

Comment: Can you please share basic documentation?