# Why does my compiled AutoIt script fail to return when called from C#?

Tags: c#, autoit

My compiled AutoIt script runs fine by itself but when called from C# it will run but does not finish executing. My compiled C# code:

```
Process myExe = new Process();
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeDir); //exeDir is full path of the AutoIt executable directory
ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("");
StartInfo.FileName = exeFile; //exeFile is full path of the executable itself
StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
myExe = Process.Start(StartInfo);
```

It halts on `EnvUpdate()` in the AutoIt code and eventually again on some other function. None of this happens if I run the executable manually.

I started a batch file from C# that runs this executable. And combinations of `CreateNoWindow` and `UseShellExecute`. Also with no success:
1) Run the C# compiled executable as Admin.
2) Use combinations of `StartInfo.CreateNoWindow` and `StartInfo.UseShellExecute`.
3) Run AutoIt executable from a batch file.
4) Run AutoIt executable from a Perl file, through a batch file.
5) Run AutoIt executable from a Windows scheduled task.
6) Run AutoIt executable without `ProcessStartInfo`, with either:

```
myExe = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c start /wait " + exeFile);
```

or

```
myExe = Process.Start(exeFile);
```

Comment: Couldn't you rather use the AutoIT class library instead for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807287/autoit-c-sharp-integration?rq=1

Comment: Not sure if I understood you fully. I would very much prefer to do all this in one language but unfortunately the C# infrastructure and AutoIT infrastructure are developed and maintained separately. I'm just trying to incorporate the latter into the former.

Comment: From their [webpage](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/): AutoItX – DLL/COM control. "Add AutoIt features to your favorite programming and scripting languages! Also features a C# assembly and PowerShell CmdLets." @Colin So you could maybe use this library and write everything in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the AutoIt code is written and constantly maintained by a different party. I will not be able to re-write it myself.

Comment: Maybe the problem is specifically how your program is running. Is your program running as administrator? Does it work without that? Is your program running using impersonation? Is it run as a service or from a planned task or in IIS or something like that?

Comment: @NineBerry I'm running the C# executable through a batch file in an Windows 10 account with admin privileges. I've tried running the batch file with 'as admin' and without. There is no service or task involved: I'm simply double-clicking the batch file myself. I'm not familiar with impersonation but in the code there is nothing that references 'impers' or 'logon'.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example C# class for an external call to a compiled AutoIt script (EXE file) using `.WaitForExit()`, which should be your problem:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RegressionTesting.Common.ThirdParty
{
    public class ClickAtBrowserPosition
    {
        public static void CallClickAtBrowserPosition(string currentBrowserWindowTitle, int xPosition, int yPosition)
        {
            var pathClickAtBrowserPosition = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathClickAtBrowserPosition"];
            var clickAtBrowserPositionExe = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clickAtBrowserPositionExe"];

            var process = new Process();
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, // don't show the cmd.exe which calls the program
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = @" /C cd " +
                            $@"""{pathClickAtBrowserPosition}"" && {clickAtBrowserPositionExe} ""{currentBrowserWindowTitle}"" {xPosition} {yPosition}"
            };

            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit(); // wait to finish the execution
        }
    }
}
```

The compiled AutoIt script is used for clicking a relative position of a window (in this case a browser).